# Maven antrun plugin run with JDK specified with toolchains plugin

Tags: maven-antrun-plugin, maven-toolchains-plugin

Is there any way to make maven run ant with a JDK that is defined using maven toolchains plugin?

Why?
I'm testing if I can convert a legacy ant based project to maven based project. Seems parts of it are next to impossible to do with maven so I need to do those with ant. At one point I need to compile using JDK 6 (and it needs to be 6, see e.g. [bootstrap class path not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15882586/bootstrap-class-path-not-set) ). Seems maven runs the antrun with the JDK version it is running and toolchains are not taken into consideration (which is ok because the https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-toolchains.html does not display antrun as compatible plugin).

Comment: Any advancements? I'm stuck with this problem too

Comment: Same issue here. Trying to upgrade maven for legacy jdk1.6 app and antrun runs as jdk1.8 (as per maven).  Tried lots of suggestions but none work

Answer (score 0):

I had maybe a related issue and and least for a subset of Java related Ant tasks the attribute [`jvm`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) or [`executable`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html) and setting `fork=true` to set the used JVM might be helpful. I assume the problem in your case might be solved with `javac` and `java`. In my example I had to use Java 8 for an older Java program not running with Java 17:

```xml
<java classname="com.sun.javacard.converter.Main"
                                      failonerror="true" fork="true"
                                      jvm="${JAVA_8_HOME}/bin/java">
                                    <jvmarg value="-Djc.home=${jc.home}"/>
...
```